# Minimum of a tail of computable function

Tags: optimization, computability

Let $G$ be a unary recursive (total computable, on natural numbers) function. Define $F$ by a formula $F(x):=\min_{y\ge x}G(y)$. Does $F$ have to be recursive?

I've solved a few hundred of tasks like this one, and usually I almost always see either an algorithm (or a nonconstructive existence of an algorithm), or a reduction from the Halting problem. But this one eludes me for almost a month already.

Of course, my hunch is that $F$ doesn't have to be recursive. But every counterexample I try to find actually has a computable $F$. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your hunch is right: $F$ **does not** have to be recursive.

For simplicity, I'll think of $F$ and $G$ as infinite sequences of natural numbers. Here's the idea: consider the sequence $G$ whose $n$th term is $2$ if $\varphi_0(0)[n]\uparrow$ and $1$ otherwise. So e.g. if $\varphi_0(0)$ halts at stage $3$, then $G$ looks like $$2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,...$$ The point is that we now have $F(0)=2$ iff $\varphi_0(0)\uparrow$, so we've encoded a bit of the halting problem into $F$.

Of course, coding one bit isn't enough - we need to do better. So what we'll do is start with a "default" sequence $G_*$ (I'd call it "$G_0$" but that would be way too confusing) and fold in a lot of "drops" which code halting facts. To accommodate dropping, $G_*$ needs to grow without bound, so let's take it to be the identity function $0,1,2,3,...$

> I'll also adopt the convention that $(i)$ for each $s$ there is at most one $e$ such that $\varphi_e(e)$ halts in exactly $s$ stages and $(ii)$ we never have $\varphi_e(e)$ halt in $\le e$ stages. *(I believe in Soare's book this is called the "hat trick," but I don't have my copy on hand. It's a good exercise to show that this isn't bogus, either by modifying the construction below to work without it or - much more flexibly - passing from the usual universal Turing machine to one with the property above.)*

Now my sequence $G$ is simple: the $s$th term of $G$ is the unique $e$ such that $\varphi_e(e)$ halts in exactly $s$ stages, if such an $e$ exists, and is $s$ itself otherwise.

- Note that by the convention above, there are only finitely many possible candidates for this $e$ (namely, if $G(s)=e$ then $e\le s$ since no program with index at least $s$ halts in $s$ steps), so $G$ is in fact computable.

For example, if $\varphi_1(1)$ halts at stage $2$, $\varphi_0(0)$ halts at stage $4$, and no programs halt at stages $0, 1$, or $3$, the sequence $G$ will begin $$0, 1, \color{red}{1}, 3, \color{red}{0}, ...$$

It's a good exercise to show that from the corresponding $F$ we can compute the halting problem.

- HINT: note that $F(e+1)\le e$ iff some $\varphi_e(e)$ halts at some stage $>e$. So to tell if $\varphi_e(e)$ halts, compute $F(e+1)$; if $F(e+1)=e$ it does and if $F(e+1)>e$ it doesn't. What if $F(e+1)<e$? Then we search for some $s\ge e+1$ such that $G(s)=F(e+1)$. Run $\varphi_e(e)$ for $s$ steps; if it halts in that time then it halts, and if it doesn't go ahead and compute $F(s)$. If $F(s)=e$ then ...

Comment: In general, the only way a function/set/etc. like this will be computable is if there is an artificial and trivializing constraint on the possible behaviors. Consider for example the set of $n$ such that there is a block of $n$ consecutive $0$s in the decimal expansion of $\pi$ *(note that it is not known whether every finite string of decimal digits occurs there!)* and the variant of $F$ given by looking at the *maximum* (and outputting $0$ if $G$ is unbounded on the tail).

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I know the one with digits of pi. And various others like that, they are grouped under "nonconstructive existence of an algorithm" in my original post above. The "hat trick" is what I missed in order to be able to solve this one. It seems useful in some other situations too. I'll have to pay closer attention to Soare in the future, I guess. Can you give me an information on what exact book of his you're talking about?

Comment: I am very thankful for the answer, but this "editing" business is pure nonsense. There is a simple typo in the answer, one $e$ should be $s$. I have an "editing privilege", presumably so I could fix these things, but it seems I cannot fix it. The edits must be at least 6 characters -- why exactly, if there is just one character wrong? It suggested I write some additional explanations, I wrote them, they were rejected. So what, now the answer has to remain with a typo? Is it possible that I'm the only one who considers this _extremely_ stupid? How is it _supposed_ to work?

Comment: @Veky You're right, there is a typo, and I have no idea why your edit was rejected. I've fixed it now. (FYI with more reputation, you get more editing powers.)